# Ubuntu 14.04 Postfix Access denied

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, email-server

Sorry to write here I'm really using it as a last resort. I have recently got my hands on a dedicated server. I'm not good with linux (not at all), but I wanted to set up a full server (Web, mail, ftp).

I did followed tutorials on how to do thinks, and all is working, except I cannot send emails from outside.

I have a Postfix / Courier mail setup ( like instructed [here](http://www.pixelinx.com/2013/09/creating-a-mail-server-on-ubuntu-postfix-courier-ssltls-spamassassin-clamav-amavis/)

Now I can use my SMTP server to send emails from my local computer, if I use sendmail on the local server it works fine email gets delivered but if I try to send an email from outside, I get hit with:

```
554 5.7.1 <>: Sender address rejected: Access denied
```

[Address has been rejected]

I spent a few hours reading and trying to solve this, most of the post suggested to change my main.cf line from:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject
```

to this:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
```

Which does make sense. I found a similar setting in master.cf as well and I have change it there as well but to no joy.

Here is my output from postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
disable_vrfy_command = yes
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 0
mydestination =
myhostname = e-systems.co.uk
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/private/mail.e-systems.co.uk.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/mail.e-systems.co.uk.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/maps/alias.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail/virtual
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/maps/domain.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/maps/user.cf
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

MX is pointing in the right place so that is ok.

Any ideas or help will be highly appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes I can be really stupid (or just tired).

The error was clear all the time: Sender rejected: Access Denied

Yet I was changing the settings for:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions
```

Now that I have see the problem I changed the line:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject
```

To:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
```

And it is working.